Auth.js "database" session strategy in Next.js
the token in auth.ts always return undefined but the session information is available.
When using the 'database' strategy The token is undefined in callbacks but Session and user data are available.  When switching to the 'jwt' strategy The token becomes available However, all the data within the token/session are null. I want to keep the session strategy : 'database' but I'm struggling to return a token for the role base authentication. I have tried multiple approaches with the callback but didn't work.
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Google from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import Resend from 'next-auth/providers/resend';
import { TypeORMAdapter } from '@auth/typeorm-adapter';
import { AppDataSource, dataSourceOptions } from '@/app/lib/db';
import * as entities from '@/app/lib/entities';

// Initialize the database connection globally
if (!AppDataSource.isInitialized) {
  AppDataSource.initialize()
    .then(() => console.log('Data Source has been initialized!'))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Error during Data Source initialization:', err);
      process.exit(1); // Exit the process if the database connection fails
    });
}

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
    Resend({
      apiKey: process.env.RESEND_API_KEY!,
      from: process.env.RESEND_FROM_EMAIL, 
    }),
  ],
  adapter: TypeORMAdapter(dataSourceOptions, { entities }),
  session: {
    strategy: 'database',
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user }): Promise<boolean> {
      try {
        const userRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository('users');
        await userRepository.update({ id: user.id }, { is_active: true });
        console.log(`User ${user.email} is now active.`);
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error activating user:', error);
        return false;
      }
    },
    // JWT callback to enrich the token
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.role = user.role; // Add the role to the token
      }
      console.log('JWT Callback - Token:', token); // Debugging
      return token;
    },
    // Session callback to include token data in the session
    async session({ session, token }) {
      console.log('Session Callback - Token:', token); // Debugging
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id as string;
        session.user.role = token.role as string; 
      }
      console.log('Session Callback - Session:', session); // Debugging
      return session;
    },
  },
});

export { dataSourceOptions, AppDataSource };

